# cannot convert radio button value to int with JQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I want to convert the value of the selected radio button to an integer.

JQuery

```
var act = $('input[name=acti:radio:checked').val();
var actInt = parseInt(act);
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="acti" value="1.95583">bla bla<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), you *should* specify a [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). In this case, `parseInt(act, 10)`.

```
var act = $('input[name=acti]:radio:checked').val(),
    actInt = parseInt(act, 10);

console.log(actInt); // 1
```

Aside from that, it looks like you were missing a `]` closing square bracket.

`$('input[name=acti:radio:checked')` -> `$('input[name=acti]:radio:checked')`

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uL4a2uy/)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a bracket.

```js
var act = $('input[name="acti"]:checked').val();
var actInt = parseInt(act, 10);
$('h3').text(actInt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="acti" value="1.95583" checked>bla bla<br>
<h3></h3>
```